# React Js Изменение компонента при наведении на кнопку

Tags: javascript, css3, reactjs, button, hover

Подскажите, как безболезненно поменять icon при наведении на кнопку. По сути надо просто заменить `type="submit"` на `type="confirm"` при наведении мышкой на кнопку

```js
import ButtonInline from '../../components/button-inline';
import Icon from '../../components/icon';

 <ButtonInline className={classes.buttonChat}>
  <Icon type="submit" size={16} className={classes.iconChat} />
  submit
</ButtonInline>
```

```css
.button-chat{}
.button-chat:hover{
    border: 1px solid #59afde;
    color: #6d717d;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #59afde;
}
```

Comment: `onmouseenter`/`onmouseleave`

Comment: этот человек говорит дело

Answer (score 1):

я для этих целей использую onMouseEnter и onMouseLeave. возможно и тут сработает.
например `<ButtonInline className={classes.buttonChat} onMouseEnter={this.hoveron} onMouseLeave={this.hoveroff}>`. и делаете функцию которая будет делать то что Вам надо, например hoveron() {} hoveroff() {}.
у меня такое работает.